# NodeJs require function not working

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to include custom modules in my nodejs application. the problem that I'm facing is that whenever I try to include custom modules it says that it can't find that module.

```
Error: Cannot find module './queue/queue'

at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/contrive/tasweel/main.js :5:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
```

I googled to find some solution but none of them worked. I transfered my project in another pc and there it was not throwing the error. After this I thought maybe there is some problem with node. So I uninstalled it and installed it again but it is still throwing me the same error.

**Node Version:** v6.9.1

**Npm Version:**   3.10.8

The way I'm trying to include the module is as followed below

```
var express = require('express');
var firebase = require("firebase");
var Queue = require('firebase-queue');
var queue = require('./queue/index'); // custom module (throwing error can't find module)
var queue = require('./index'); // custom module (throwing error can't find module)
var app = express();
```

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit

Folder structure:

```
-node-modules
-queue
  -index.js
-worker.js
-main.js // entry point for node application
```

Please tell me why am I facing this error. Thanks

Comment: if there is no filesystem reference to what you are point then this error is thrown. it's difficult to tell without seeing what's in your filesystem

Comment: What is the path name to your module that has the require in it and what is the path name to the module you are requiring?

Comment: @DanD. The file that is requiring is at the root of the project and the file that I'm requiring is in a folder named queue which is also at root the root of the project and the name of the file is index

Comment: You didn't try `require('./queue')`.

Comment: @DanD. I tried that but that is not working also

Comment: @DevZer0 what do you mean by file system reference

Comment: What output does this command produce? `find -name "*.js" -not -path "./node_modules/*"`

Comment: @allonhadaya it produces this output `./worker.js
`

Comment: Well, you may technically have valid code in a file without the `.js` extension, but most likely you've specified a relative file path incorrectly. Take a look at node's [module documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules).

Comment: It would be great if you include folder structure and OS details. You may like to check file and folder permission as well.

Comment: @allonhadaya it has ha `.js` extension and the path is correct. Well I'll debug more to see why am I facing this problem

Comment: Okay, good luck! Remember, the require paths are relative between the files, and not to any sort of project root.

Comment: NodeJS automatically detect index file, if package.json is not exist in folder. If queue is folder and it contains index.js, then you can simply go this var queue = require('./queue'). Have you tries as mentioned before?

Comment: @hilarudeens yes I have tried but it is not working. I'm very surprised that this is only coming in my new laptop. I transferred my project in my other laptop and it's working fine over ther.

Comment: What is your OS? Can You try with fresh  git clone. And check is there any simlink and aliases?. This may create issue.